# Different Fonts in Latex Article Class

Tags: fonts, sectioning

Suppose I want to set a font that is universal in the article, report or book document class (such as Times New Roman) but have specific sections that I want to use a different font. How would I go about that? Would this require the mini-page environment? Or would a command to tell LaTeX where one font stops and another begins would suffice?

Here is an example to illustrate my question

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accanthis}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\begin{document}

%This first part should be in the default `Times New Roman`
\blindtext

\section{New cent}
%I want this section in `Newcent` Fant

\fontfamily{newcent}
\blindtext

\section{Accanthis}
%This section in `accanthis`

\fontseries{accanthis}
\blindtext

\section{Typewriter}
%This in `typewriter`

\fontfamily{tgcursos}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using pdfTeX with type1 fonts (not XeTeX, not LuaTeX): what follows assume this.

To set Times New Roman as the default font, load the `newtxtext` package.  However, if you load other font packages after it, they might overwrite the default; so:

- either load `newtxtext` as the last font package,
- or do not load other font packages at all.

In particular, you can define “by hand” the commands you need to select other font families.  If you issue those commands inside a group, the default font will be restored when the group ends.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*\accanthisfamily{%
    \fontfamily{AccanthisADFStdNoThree-LF}\selectfont
}
\newcommand*\newcentfamily{\fontfamily{pnc}\selectfont}
\newcommand*\tgcursorfamily{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont}



\begin{document}

%This first part should be in the default `Times New Roman`
\blindtext

The current (external) font name is ``\fontname\font''.

\section{New cent}
%I want this section in `Newcent` Fant

\begingroup
    \newcentfamily

    The current (external) font name is ``\fontname\font''.

    \blindtext

\endgroup

\section{Accanthis}
%This section in `accanthis`

\begingroup
    \accanthisfamily

    The current (external) font name is ``\fontname\font''.

    \blindtext

\endgroup

\section{Typewriter}
%This in `typewriter`

\begingroup
    \tgcursorfamily

    The current (external) font name is ``\fontname\font''.

    \blindtext

\endgroup

Back to default font.

The current (external) font name is ``\fontname\font''.

\end{document}
```